# Multiple boost trails possible?

Tags: rocket-league

On [RocketLeagueValues](https://rocketleaguevalues.com/item/TACHYON) I read for the Tachyon, Season 2 Champion or other rocket trails:

> It depends on your Battle-Car how many boost trails your car has

Does that mean that there are cars that can have 2 or more boost trails assigned at the same time? How would I assign that then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they mean how many trails come out the back of the car.

For instance, notice that when [the Gizmo boosts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baA1iMxzFAk#t=1m07s) there's only one smoke trail behind it, but when [the Merc boosts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgg03Z_xOoE#t=2m54s) there's two (stacked vertically on top each other)

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Thanks for the video links. Never noticed that Merc has two...

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I think over half of the cars have two, including the Octane (the most popular car)

Comment: Masamune has 2.

Comment: horizontally aligned